# Populate cellForRowAtIndexPath for grouped tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a uitableview (NOT a UITableViewController) with 2 sections inside the uitableview. For the other methods I was able to rely on a switch case to figure out what section should be populated with the correct data.

```
switch(section) {
    case 0:
       return postitiveArray.count

    case 1:
       return negativeArray.count

    default :return 0
}
```

But cellForRowAtIndexPath doesn't seem to have that option. So how can I populate one section with postitiveArray and the other section with negativeArray?

Comment: Why don't you think `cellForRowAtIndexPath` has that option? Look at the `indexPath` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` method supplies you with an `NSIndexPath`, which has `row` and `section` properties. So you just need to get the `section` property from it to determine which section you're in.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this!